# Can ArcGIS Server render Mapbox Vector Tiles?

Tags: arcgis-server, mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

I am planning to build an application using Mapbox GL JS. All the data sources I need to import are stored on an ArcGIS server 10.5.

There are several feature layers on this server which I'll be able to render in Mapbox GL by requesting GeoJSON from the server using code like [from this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798531/consume-arcgis-server-rest-services-api-into-mapbox-gl-api#).

```
map.on('load', function () {
    // Add a layer showing the city parks
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'parks-layer',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': 'https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/ArcGIS/rest/services/City_of_Redlands_Parks/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outSR=4326&f=pgeojson'
        },
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': 'rgba(200, 100, 240, 0.3)',
            'fill-outline-color': 'rgba(200, 100, 240, 1)'
        }
    });
});
```

This will work fine for datasets that are smaller and won't slow down the application. There are also larger datasets on the server such as land-ownership which are quite large. Is there any way to request mapbox vector tiles from an ArcGIS server for rendering in Mapbox GL JS?

Comment: you may be able to create something (not direct to vector tiles) with - https://koopjs.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct, you are trying to issues requests for tiles (not the entire layer) in order to optimize the performance for the layers with many features? According to [this][1] blog post, tile requests in OGC format are supported even for MapBox sources thru ArcGIS API.

More information here

https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles/ 
https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/07/20/vector-tiles-preview/